# Association bonus issue on merging of user accounts

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-accounts, association-bonus

I had an Stack Overflow account earlier (created in August 2011), which was recently merged with a new account I created in December 2012.

When reputation for the new account reached 200, I got the association bonus on sites I joined with that new account. After the merge, though, I didn't get the association bonus for sites which I joined before creating the new account. Is this normal?

For example, I haven't received the association bonus here on Meta, which I joined earlier.

Comment: Easy, folks. Abin's current account is in good standing. Let's focus on the actual issue here, which is the association bonus (or lack thereof).

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like a potential bug to me. This *might* be an issue of reputation taking a while to update, but I'll ping someone tomorrow to take a closer look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your association bonus has now been granted. I'll take a look into the merge case a bit more but this seems *incredibly* rare, and is currently picked up by a network-wide scan we run every couple of weeks and has only a handful of users.