# After 2 accounts were merged, I didn't receive the reputation bonus on one site

Tags: bug, merge-accounts, association-bonus

I recently created a new account on the Parenting Stack Exchange site, and in the course of 3 days, earned ≈400 reputation. I later realized that my other accounts hadn't received the reputation bonus, and found out that I had created 2 different accounts. I requested to merge my accounts on the Unix and Linux Stack Exchange site, and within a few days, I got an email telling me that my accounts had been merged. For some strange reason, however, all of my accounts EXCEPT that of my Unix and Linux Stack Exchange account had received the association bonus. Why did this happen?

Comment: What's your intent with this question? It's tagged as a [tag:bug], which implies it's *only* reporting a general bug in the system, but you've asked "why did this happen", which isn't just a bug report and changes the focus of the question. You originally tagged this as [tag:support], which implies what you're looking for is to have your accounts fixed, but the only way for that to happen is for SE staff to handle it. The appropriate and effective way to ask for staff assistance *for a specific account* is for you to use the "contact"/"contact us" link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Makyen obviously, the bug is not getting the association bonus. I'm not sure what's your intent with that comment. You want people to not report bugs here?

Comment: [Very much related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162075/association-bonus-issue-on-merging-of-user-accounts), based on the answer looks like you're one of those rare cases, so you should get the bonus within couple of weeks unless a developer will spot this and give it manually like Nick did.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard "looks like you're one of those rare cases" Very comforting to know.

Comment: @Shadow No. It's good and appropriate to report the bug here. However, the issue is covering the *poster's intent*. *Most people* in the OP's situation are primarily interested in resolving *their account's* issue (as indicated by the first revision's [tag:support] tag), rather than reporting a bug in the system. That the issue is account related means the only resolution is to have SE staff handle the individual case (baring the maybe auto-resolution in a couple weeks mentioned in your link). The *effective* way to ask for staff support for an account is through "contact"/"contact us".

Comment: Back in 2013, when the Q&A you linked was posted, it was *much* more likely for a staff member to be monitoring meta, see such a report and resolve the individual problem. At this point, that's far less likely for that to happen (but it does, sometimes). I was trying to communicate that if the OP wants resolution for *their account* then the way to get that in a timely manner is to use "contact"/"contact us" to ask for assistance from SO Staff for their specific account.

Comment: @Makyen Another way that people can think of it as a bug is to perceive the bug as "my account wasn't [x]" instead of "some accounts in general weren't [x]". In other words, any behavior that is obviously incorrect is a bug, even though it may not be generally related to everyone, and a support question is for things where someone isn't sure if it's a bug.